# bootstrap.php file in CodeIgniter PHP framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in php. I am learning Code Igniter (a PHP framework). Can anybody let me know is there any bootstrap.php file in codeIgniter ? And if yes then what it does?

I googled but no luck for bootstrap.php file for CodeIgniter, however i got the bootstrap.php file for Zend and one other framework.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the relation to cakephp

Answer (score 3):

### application/config

From the question, I'm assuming you would like to know where this file is to add something to it.

The bootstrap file in [CakePHP](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/bootstrap.php) is for additional application settings and setup logic - the equivalent file in Codigniter is probably the [application/config/config.php](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php) file.

The bootstrap file in [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.examples.html) contains a class used for initializing the whole application , which by default reads a config.ini file. Depending on specifically what it is you're looking for in "bootstrap.php file in CodeIgniter" - again, the [application config files](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/tree/develop/application/config) are the CI equivalent of this file's logic/purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The CodeIgniter bootstrap file is the CodeIgniter.php located in system/core.